# Where are cookie files stored? - PHP Wamp

Tags: php, cookies

Am using WAMP server for PHP development. I have created a cookie in my php but can't locate the cookie file being created. The `php.ini` reads `session.save_path=C:/wamp/tmp` and none of the files have been created today. The code is:

```
<?php
      $mycookie="mycookie";
      $emailAddr="abc@gmail.com";
      if (!isset($_COOKIE[$mycookie]))
      {
           if (!setcookie($mycookie, $emailAddr, 0))
           {
                 echo "Cannot set cookie";
           }
           else
                 echo "Cookie is set";
      }
?>
```

I get "Cookie is set" message but checking C:/wamp/tmp does not see any cookie file created today.

Comment: Cookies aren't session, and are stored client-sided, not server-sided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cookies are stored individually depending on a browser. they store them in their own folders.

what you are setting in your php.ini is the session path. which is the path for saving sessions `$_SESSION` not cookies `$_COOKIES`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to confuse cookie and session. Cookies are stored on the client side while sessions are stored on the server side. Although sessions often use a cookie, it is only used to store the session ID but not the actual data.

The actual storage location of cookies depends on the user agent. Most store them in files in the client’s file system. The session’s storage location is specified with [*session.save_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) (except if you’re using a [storage handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) other than the default).

Besides that, [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie) does always return *true* except for when the corresponding [*Set-Cookie* header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1) could not be send due to the fact that the HTTP header has already been sent and hence cannot be modified anymore. The return value of `setcookie` doesn’t say anything about whether the cookie was accepted or not.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are not stored server-side.  The point of cookies is to have info stored on the browser so that the info is sustained between pages.  If you want something server-side similar to cookies, you'll want to use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).